# When to use private interface methods over private static methods?

Tags: java, interface

For Java 9 and on, I understand that `private` interface methods can be declared and implemented in the interface, then called by `default` interface methods (of the same interface).

But, `private` interface methods cannot be called by `static` interface methods.

Now, I also understand that `private static` interface methods can be declared/implemented in the interface, then called by `default` as well as `static` methods.

So it seems to me that the abilities of a `private static` interface method is a 'superset' of a `private` interface method.

If that is the case, is there any situation where using a `private` interface method is preferable to using a `private static` interface method?

For example:

```
public interface Schedule {
    default void wakeUp() { checkTime(7); }
    // static void sleep() { checkTime(21); } // compile error if private interface method called
    private void checkTime(int time) { // if so, why not always use private static method instead?
        // implementation omitted
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the private, non-static method could also call another public method of the interface, and if it were static, that would not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-static method can itself call other instance methods.

```
public interface Schedule {
    LocalTime getCurrentTime();

    default void wakeUp() { checkTime(7); }

    private void checkTime(int time) {
        if (getCurrentTime().isAfter(/*something*/)) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

If it were static, it couldn't do that. If you don't need to call another instance method, make it static.

This is pretty much the same logic you should follow when writing a normal class.